# How to make AngularJS Materials drop down menues more visable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I was playing around with AngularJS Materials and was using  and . I realized that it maybe really hard to read for some people because of how light the text is and I wanted to make it visible without changing the background.

I managed to make the color of plain text of  this in css:

```
    md-input-container.md-default-theme label, md-input-container label, md-input-container.md-default-theme .md-placeholder, md-input-container .md-placeholder{
  color: black;
}
```

I don't necessarily need to make it darker but I was wondering if there was any kind of method to make the drop down menu of AngularJS Materials more visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the textcolor by overriding md-menu-item. This will take some screwing around with since you'll probably need to !important certain classes to override material design.

```
md-menu-content.md-default-theme md-menu-item, md-menu-content md-menu-item {
    color: some color
}
```

They are buttons inside of a dropdown so $mdThemeProvider should work to change them if you want to go about it that way.

Just add the class **md-primary**, **md-accent**, or **md-warn** to one of these material elements (md-button in your case):
md-button, md-checkbox, md-progress-circular, md-progress-linear, md-radio-button, md-slider, md-switch, md-tabs, md-input-container, md-toolbar

adding md-raised to a button with .md-primary inverses the color effect so .md-primary.md-raised makes the background blue and text white

```
  <md-menu>
    <md-button ng-class="md-raised" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" aria-label="Open sample menu">
      test menu
    </md-button>
    <md-menu-content>
      <md-menu-item>
        //
        //add md-primary on the button for blue text
        //change $mdThemeProvider if you want the color to be different
        //
        <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
  </md-menu>
```

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/02_declarative_syntax

EDIT: working snippet for md-menu

```js
var app = angular.module('sandbox', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>

<link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-animate.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sandbox">
  <div layout-margin>
    <div layout="row">
      <md-menu>
        <!-- Trigger element is a md-button with an icon -->
        <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" aria-label="Open sample menu" class="md-raised">
          test menu
        </md-button>
        <md-menu-content>
          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="doSomething()">Do Something</md-button>
          </md-menu-item>
        </md-menu-content>
      </md-menu>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2nd EDIT:**

**OP was actually talking about the label in an md-select.**

That can only be changed through css manipulation.

Now it may seem like the obvious choice to just change

```
md-input-container label {
   some color    
}
```

However, angular-materials actually puts the first md-select-value as it's label

```
<md-input-container class="">
   <label for="select_5" class="md-placeholder">Drop Down Tester</label>
   <md-select ng-model="selectedUser" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-multiselectable="false" id="select_5" aria-owns="select_container_6" aria-invalid="false" aria-label="Drop Down Tester">
       <md-select-value class="md-select-value md-select-placeholder" id="select_value_label_0">
          <span>Drop Down Tester</span>
          <span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </md-select-value>
    </md-select>
 </md-input-container>
```

If you want to change your placeholder for md-select,

```
md-select.md-default-theme .md-select-value.md-select-placeholder, md-select .md-select-value.md-select-placeholder {
  color: green;
}
```

This will not change the underline or override md-primary or other stylings, just the placeholder with zero actions.

```js
var app = angular.module('sandbox', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```css
md-select.md-default-theme .md-select-value.md-select-placeholder, md-select .md-select-value.md-select-placeholder {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>

<link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-animate.js"></script>

<body ng-app="sandbox">
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Drop Down Tester</label>
      <md-select ng-model="selectedUser">
        <md-option>Hello</md-option>
        <md-option>Please Change Color</md-option>
        <md-option>Pls</md-option>
        <md-option>Do it for your mother Mr.Select</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
  </md-content>
</body>
```

Comment: I maybe doing it wrong but it doesn't seem to be working in my example http://plnkr.co/edit/0D6bYrtidB5rRAOy14MD?p=preview

Comment: this isn't an md-menu. I'll adjust the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Sorry about my bad question description.

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I could help.